# React Native: Image is not properly showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am running into an issue when trying to display the image. I'm not sure where to go from here. I am importing it correctly and this is a example of a tutorial that I am doing but the author images are displayed but mines are not. What could be the issue? I am following line by line from this tutorial.

ImageScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import ImageDetail from './components/ImageDetail.js';

const ImageScreen = () => {
    return (
        <><View>
            <Text>Hi</Text>
        </View><View>
                <ImageDetail
                    title="Forest"
                    imageSource={require('../../assets/forest.jpg')}
                    score={9} />
                <ImageDetail
                    title="Beach"
                    imageSource={require('../../assets/beach.jpg')}
                    score={7} />
                <ImageDetail
                    title="Mountain"
                    imageSource={require('../../assets/mountain.jpg')}
                    score={10} />
            </View></>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ImageScreen;
```

ImageDetail.js

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';


    const ImageDetail = props => {
        return(
            <View>
                <Image source={props.imageSource}/>
                <Text>{props.title}</Text>;
                <Text>Image Score - {props.score}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
    
    export default ImageDetail;
```

App.js

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/screens/HomeScreen";
import ComponentsScreen from "./src/screens/screens/ComponentsScreen";
import ListScreen from "./src/screens/screens/ListScreen";
import ImageScreen from "./src/screens/ImageScreen";
import CounterScreen from "./src/screens/screens/CounterScreen";
import ColorScreen from "./src/screens/screens/ColorScreen";
import SquareScreen from "./src/screens/screens/SquareScreen";
import TextScreen from "./src/screens/screens/TextScreen";
import BoxScreen from "./src/screens/screens/BoxScreen";
import PhoneCall from "./src/screens/screens/PhoneCall";
import DoctorResults from "./src/screens/DoctorResults";

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Components: ComponentsScreen,
    List: ListScreen,
    Image: ImageScreen,
    Counter: CounterScreen,
    Color: ColorScreen,
    Square: SquareScreen,
    Text: TextScreen,
    Box: BoxScreen,
    Phone: PhoneCall,
    Doctor: DoctorResults,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: "App",
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

[Here's the results but I don't get any image to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKUQr.jpg)

Comment: Please post code, not images of code, which can't be searched, copied/pasted, or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try giving some width and height to the image component like

```
 <Image
   style={{width: 50, height: 50}} //or 100%
   source={require("dir")} // Make sure image dir is correct
   />
```

Hope it will help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please **check** your **image directory** is **correct** or not.

**Ctrl+Click** to your **image assets directory.**
If image can open, it is correct route. If not, you need to check your image directory again.

`imageSource={(require('../../assets/image.png'))}`

I try with your code and show like this. I think problem is with your image and image directory.
Please try to add width and height in image.

```
    <View>
        <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100}} source= {props.imageSource} />
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        <Text>Image Score - {props.score}</Text>
    </View>
```

[image]

Comment: The images are opening to the correct route.

Comment: I try with your code, it works well with image. How about to try close metro server and run your app again.

Comment: Or can you pls try with another small image size?

Comment: Thank you! It works when adding dimensions!

Comment: Welcome and nice to hear ^^)